# NPM package 'http-server' seems to 404 arbitrary asset paths

Tags: node.js, npm, httpserver

I have a simple folder that I want to serve to localhost as a bunch of static assets.  The file structure looks something like this:

- build

  - assets
  - data
  - images
  - index.html

I installed http-server via NPM using `npm install http-server -g` and I'm serving this directory (build) full of static files to localhost using:

```
cd ~/MyProject/build
http-server .
```

The result is that I can visit `localhost:8080` in my browser and I get index.html loading as expected.  However, it loads incompletely, and in the console I see that a JS file (in the /assets path) referenced in index.html *is* loading and running correctly, but `http-server` is returning 404 for relative path assets in the /data path.  In other words, the following browser console error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/data/myFile.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Attempting to reach this asset by direct path also fails, e.g. by typing in my browser address bar:

```
http://localhost:8080/data/myFile.json
```

However, if I move this asset into the /images path (just as an experiment) then it works.  In other words, the following in the browser address bar does return the desired file:

```
http://localhost:8080/images/myFile.json
```

Also tested by installing ExpressJS in this project, and creating a simple NodeJS script configured to serve the 'build' directory (same physical directory with no file structure or naming alterations).  It worked perfectly with no path or filename alterations, so I know the file structure and names are good.  Something is fishy just with `http-server`.  In the meantime, I'm just using ExpressJS as a solution, which is fine, but now I'm curious what the problem is in http-server because it's a very handy solution for the future if I can get it working!

Why can `http-server` find index.html and /assets path, but not /data path?  Is the /data path illegal or have I done anything wrong?  Is there a configuration I can alter in `http-server` to make this feasible?  I can't rename the /data path because unalterable minified vendor JS refers to this path.

Comment: Does the requested file exist, and with that exact filename?

Comment: @robertklep yes, verified it does exist, at that path and filename.  If I move the designated file to the /images path instead, it works there.  It seems only the /data path returns 404.  I'll update my question with this new information.  (Unfortunately I cannot change the name of this /data path due to project restrictions.)

Comment: I assume that you're loading the file through an XHR/fetch call? Does it work when you open its URL directly? Or using a CLI tool like cURL?

Comment: Correct, it appears to come via XHR but I can't see the details in the vendor's minified JS of how this is done.  However, when I attempt to reach the file directly, e.g. http://localhost:8080/data/myFile.json this also returns 404.  Wondering if the /data path name is simply illegal in http-server module

Comment: Yeah I tested that myself but it works okay, there's also nothing in the code that suggests that it's treated as special.

Comment: Just to experiment, I installed ExpressJS in this project directory and configured it to serve the 'build' directory, and it worked perfectly with no path or filename alterations, so I know the file structure and names are good.  Something is fishy just with `http-server`.